# Migrate local TFS to Team Foundation Service

Tags: tfs, migration, azure-devops, tfs-migration

I am trying to migrate my local TFS server to http://tfs.visualstudio.com/. My goal is to preserve code history, work items and etc.

Does this feature exists and if it how to use it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've used the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) to migrate between two TFS servers. The one issue you might run into is the check-in dates are reset to the day of the migration (basically what you are doing is checking in all of the code), but the original check-in date is recorded in the check-in comments.