# Migrate TFS 2010 to Team Foundation Service

Tags: azure-devops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrate local TFS to Team Foundation Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312873/migrate-local-tfs-to-team-foundation-service)

We are looking to move the code on our self hosted TFS over to the new Team Foundation Service, but we're not seeing any options to do this.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the ALM Rangers' [Team Foundation Server Migration Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe). This requires some tricks to put your account the `TFS Service` account group on both the Team Foundation Service and your source machine [via the command line](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/tfs-integration-tools-issue-tfs-wit-bypass-rule-submission-is-enabled/).

```
 TFSSecurity.exe /g+ "Team Foundation Service Accounts" n:USERNAME /server:SERVERNAME
```

Notice that you cannot migrate any custom(ized) Process templates. The Team Foundation Service only supports the standard process templates, so you might need to map the fields in order to make the migration work.

You could also use [Git-TF](http://gittf.codeplex.com/) to create a local copy of the Source Control and then commit the code to the Team Foundation Service. This will not migrate branches and work items, but is very simple to do.